# Sum values of multi dimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, soap, multidimensional-array

I have this multi dimensional array

```
array(192) {
   [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#29 (16) {
   ["campaignId"]=>
     int(746598)
   ["creativeId"]=>
     int(11062415)
   ["targetId"]=>
     int(814283)
   ["targetStatus"]=>
     string(6) "ACTIVE"
   ["impressions"]=>
     int(9)
   ["clicks"]=>
     int(0)
   ["cost"]=>
     float(0.3003)
   ["ctr"]=>
     NULL
   ["cpm"]=>
     float(33.3667)
   ["conversions"]=>
     int(2)
   ["revenue"]=>
     float(4)
   ["cpa"]=>
     float(0.1502)
   ["cr"]=>
     float(22.22222)
   ["averageRank"]=>
     float(1.9)
   ["maxBid"]=>
     float(0.884)
   ["averageBid"]=>
     float(0.0334)
   }
[1]=>
   object(stdClass)#29 (16) {
   ["campaignId"]=>
     int(746598)
   ["creativeId"]=>
     int(11062415)
   ["targetId"]=>
     int(814283)
   ["targetStatus"]=>
     string(6) "ACTIVE"
   ["impressions"]=>
     int(9)
   ["clicks"]=>
     int(0)
   ["cost"]=>
     float(0.3003)
   ["ctr"]=>
     NULL
   ["cpm"]=>
     float(33.3667)
   ["conversions"]=>
     int(2)
   ["revenue"]=>
     float(4)
   ["cpa"]=>
     float(0.1502)
   ["cr"]=>
     float(22.22222)
   ["averageRank"]=>
     float(1.9)
   ["maxBid"]=>
     float(0.884)
   ["averageBid"]=>
     float(0.0334)
   }
[2]=>
    object(stdClass)#29 (16) {
    ["campaignId"]=>
      int(746595)
    ["creativeId"]=>
      int(11062415)
    ["targetId"]=>
      int(814283)
    ["targetStatus"]=>
      string(6) "ACTIVE"
    ["impressions"]=>
       int(9)
    ["clicks"]=>
      int(0)
    ["cost"]=>
      float(0.3003)
    ["ctr"]=>
      NULL
    ["cpm"]=>
      float(33.3667)
    ["conversions"]=>
      int(2)
    ["revenue"]=>
      float(4)
    ["cpa"]=>
     float(0.1502)
    ["cr"]=>
      float(22.22222)
    ["averageRank"]=>
      float(1.9)
    ["maxBid"]=>
      float(0.884)
    ["averageBid"]=>
      float(0.0334)
   }
  [3]=>
object(stdClass)#29 (16) {
   ["campaignId"]=>
     int(746595)
    ["creativeId"]=>
      int(11062415)
    ["targetId"]=>
     int(814283)
   ["targetStatus"]=>
      string(6) "ACTIVE"
   ["impressions"]=>
      int(9)
   ["clicks"]=>
     int(0)
   ["cost"]=>
     float(0.3003)
   ["ctr"]=>
     NULL
   ["cpm"]=>
    float(33.3667)
   ["conversions"]=>
     int(2)
   ["revenue"]=>
     float(4)
   ["cpa"]=>
     float(0.1502)
   ["cr"]=>
     float(22.22222)
   ["averageRank"]=>
     float(1.9)
   ["maxBid"]=>
     float(0.884)
   ["averageBid"]=>
     float(0.0334)
   }
 }
}
```

I want to sum the values of cost and get the average of cpm every campaign id and I only get the last part of the array.

This is my code

```
while (strtotime($startDate) <= strtotime($endDate)) {
    $newStartDate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startDate)));

    $params = array(
        'date'=> $newStartDate
    );
    $reports = $client->__soapCall('getDailyTargetsStats', array($params));

    $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
    $cost = 0;
    $resultArray = $reports->stats->item;
    foreach ($resultArray as $value) {
        $campaignId = $value->campaignId;
        $cost += $value->cost;

        if ((!$newStartDate) || (!$campaignId)) {
            continue;
        }
        //get campaign names
        $campaignName =  $this->get_campaigns($campaignId);

        $data = array(
            'date' => $newStartDate,
            'campaign_id' => $campaignId,
            'campaign_name' => $campaignName,
            'cost' => $cost
        );
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($data);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;   
    }
    sleep(5);
    $startDate = $newStartDate;
}
```

Any suggestions will do, I am currently developing it in CodeIgniter and PHP 5.6.

Then current code now is this

```
foreach ($resultArray as $value) {
                $campaignId = $value->campaignId;
                $cost += $value->cost;

                if ((!$newStartDate) || (!$campaignId)) {
                    continue;
                }

                //get campaign names
                $campaignName =  $this->get_campaigns($campaignId);

                $data = array(
                    'date' => $newStartDate,
                    'campaign_id' => $campaignId,
                    'campaign_name' => $campaignName,
                    'cost' => $cost
                );



            }
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($data);
            echo '</pre>';
            exit;
```

Comment: looks like you are exiting the script during the end of the first iteration.  move the `var_dump()` and the `exit` outside of the loop

Comment: i already moved it.

Comment: please update your post to reflect the current code and also post the result of `var_dump($data)`

Comment: nothing has been reflected its still loading

Comment: I already updated the post

Comment: is your `$cost` value coming out correctly?

Comment: not yet still.  its just loading in my browser

Comment: Are you testing with the data you posted here? It's difficult to tell exactly what results you are seeing and what you want to see.  From your code, it looks like the total of the cost should be correct.

Comment: perhaps you want to make `$data` an array of arrays by changing it to `$data[] = array(...`

Comment: yes correct, okay let me try it

Comment: But in my code I want it to be group by the same id, the result must the total of cost of the same campaign ID

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
foreach ($resultArray as $value) {
    $campaignId = $value->campaignId;
    $newStartDate = $value->newStartDate;

    if ((!$newStartDate) || (!$campaignId)) {
        continue;
    }

    $cost = $value->cost;

    //get campaign names
    $campaignName = $this->get_campaigns($campaignId);

    $data[campaign_id] = array(
        'date' => $newStartDate,
        'campaign_id' => $campaignId,
        'campaign_name' => $campaignName,
        'cost' => $data['campaign_name'] + $cost
    );
}
```